# How do I get an instance of IProgressMonitor?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin and I would like to get an instance of IProgressMonitor to pass it to native eclipse code. What I would like exactly is an IProgressMonitor that notifies users through the "Progress" view.

I found lot of documentation about how use an existing IProgressMonitor like [this page](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Progress-Monitors/article.html) but nothing about getting such IProgressMonitor instance. The only implementations I found are those referenced from [IProgressMonitor's JavaDoc](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/ntopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor.html) but none seems to be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things give you an `IProgressMonitor`.

If you run your code as a `Job` (`org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job`) then the `run` method that you implement is given a progress monitor. Also the related `UIJob` and `WorkspaceJob` classes.

In the `IRunnableWithProgress` interface, the `run` method is given a progress monitor. Several things support this interface such as

- In a wizard the `run` method of `IWizardContainer`
- The `run` method of `ProgressMonitorDialog`
- The `IWorkbenchWindow` workbench window.
- The jface `ProgressMonitorPart` class.
- `WorkspaceModifyOperation`
- Anything else that implements `IRunnableContext`

You can even use `NullProgressMonitor` to create your own monitor (which does nothing)

Comment: Thanks, I used `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getProgressService()` which give me an instance of an `IRunnableContext` then I called the `run` method as advised. The resulting behavior does not write in the progress view but it opens a progress bar dialog which is good enough for my needs.